# File not downloaded and being timeout with PHP and using Expect

Tags: php, expect

I've two files, script.php (to run the expect files), script.exp (the expect files to get / download files), but I've some problem on script.exp the file that I want download is not being downloaded, I'm pretty sure the code is almost right and now I'm stuck, please help, this is my code :

> script.php

```
function downloadreal(){
exec("expect /home/script.exp");}
```

> script.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set pass "password"
    spawn sftp -oPort=2123 sftp@ftp.mynet.com
    expect "*you sure you want to continue*"
    send "yes \r"
    expect {
        timeout {puts "Time out!"; exit}
        "*password:"
    }
    send "$pass\n"
    expect "*sftp>"
    send "ls -l \r"
    expect "*sftp>"
    send "get *.csv \r"
    expect "*sftp>"
    send "bye \r"
    expect ""
    expect "*\r"
    expect "\r"
```

Thankyou

Comment: will it  take more than 10 seconds to download those files? Before you send `get`, you might want to `set timeout -1`

Comment: i' try that before but it give result never ending looping and when i try to add `expect {
        "(yes/no)" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "password"
    }` the problem is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, add this code on script.exp :

```
expect {
        "(yes/no)" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "password"
    }
```

so, the final code will be like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set pass "password"
    spawn sftp -oPort=2123 sftp@ftp.mynet.com
    expect {
        "(yes/no)" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "password"
    }
    send "$pass\n"
    expect "*sftp>"
    send "ls -l \r"
    expect "*sftp>"
    send "get *.csv \r"
    expect "*sftp>"
    send "bye \r"
    expect ""
    expect "*\r"
    expect "\r"
```

Thanks, i'd solved it